# Ordering ActiveRecord instances according to their children's specific attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two ActiveRecord models - `Residence` and `Apartment`.

```
class Residence < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apartments
end

class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :residence
end
```

`apartments` table has fields  `price_from` (unit price) and `area`. so total price for an apartment is `price_from`*`area`

I've also defined an instance method for residences

```
def min_price_for_apartment
  apartments.minimum("price_from*area")
end
```

I am able to sort residences in ascending/descending order with calling this scope.

```
#scope: with_children, -> { where(published: true).includes(:apartments).joins(:apartments) }

scope: sort_by_unit_price_asc, -> { with_children.order('apartments.price_from') }
# scope: sort_by_unit_price_asc, ->{adding desc to the end of previous scope}
```

What should I do to sort residences by their minimum apartment price?

**UPDATE:** i've found a solution with pure sql, now need to translate it to AR

```
# select residences.name from residences inner join apartments on residences.id = apartments.residence_id group by (residences.id) order by min(apartments.price_from*apartments.area)

   name    
-----------
 Lorem
 Ipsum
 Quod
 Maritimus
 Amet
(5 rows)
```

P.S. I am aware of other related questions and answers on SO, but none of them helped me. I am also aware of to implement a frontend based solution, with passing such values to `data-attributes` and sort according to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved my problem. just adding for future reference if anyone will need.

```
  scope :with_children, -> { where(published: true).joins(:apartments).group('residences.id') }

  scope :sort_by_price_sqm_asc, -> { with_children.order("MIN(apartments.price_from)") }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scope: sort_by_unit_price_asc, lambda {                
  with_children.group('residences.id').order('MIN(apartments.price_from * apartments.area')
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i've already tried this, and get such error  `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "apartments.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

p.s. put single quote after parathesis -))
p.p.s have a look up to update on my question.